# JQuery find all data- elements

Tags: jquery, element

I'm data binding by adding a html5 data- custom attribute to an element

```
<div id="fred">
<input type="text" data-fld="Field1" value="10" />
<input type="text" data-fld="Field2" value="11" />
<input type="text" data-fld="Field3" value="12" />
<input type="text" value="13" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to search for all elements that have a data-fld specified.

```
col = div.find("[data-fld!='']");
```

But no luck with what I've tried this far.

Here's a jsfiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/p2KsP/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to use a [Has Attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
var col = $("#fred").find("[data-fld]");
console.log(col.length);  // 3
```

An [Attribute Not Equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) will not work because it matches elements that *either don't have the specified attribute*, or *do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value*. It means `[data-fld!='']` will end up matching all elements.

Comment: Thank you, yes that seems to work. Can you explain why !='' did not work ? Just interested and learning !

Comment: @user, that's because `[data-fld!='']` does not do what you think it does. I tried to elaborate that point in my answer.